# Show that the multiplicative group of integers mod 35 is not isomorphic to the additive group of integers mod 24

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I got this question on an abstract algebra test back when I was still in undergrad. I was going over some old notes from undergrad (just for fun) and I realized I had a completely wrong answer to this question so I set about trying to solve it. I am really struggling with it. To be honest, I think I just have a hard time disproving two groups are isomorphic unless they have different cardinality.

Any suggestions?

Comment: not only must the orders of the groups be the same to be isomorphic, but even the orders of the elements must be the same

Comment: As something of a higher-level hint, proving two groups are not isomorphic typically involves searching for some invariant property that one group has that the other group doesn't. Simpleminded properties include the order of the group (which you have identified) and orders of elements (which J. W. Tanner identifies). More complex invariants includes conjugacy classes, normal subgroups, and presumably an infinite family of even more complex ideas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:**

Can you show, $\forall n\in(\mathbb Z/35\mathbb Z)^\times$, $n^{12}\equiv1\bmod35$?

Comment: Is there a trick to doing this without solving for all the subgroups generated by all 24 elements of (Z/35Z)×?

Comment: Yes; $n^6\equiv1\bmod7$ and $n^4\equiv1\bmod5$ (Fermat's little theorem), so $n^{12}\equiv1\bmod7$ and $\bmod5$, so $\bmod 35$

Comment: I had forgotten about Fermat's little theorem. Unfortunately, if I remember correctly, I believe I learned Fermat's little theorem in number theory, which I took after abstract algebra. Still, definitely a good way to go about it.

Answer (score 7):

The multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}_{35})^{\times}$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}_{5})^{\times} \times (\mathbb{Z}_{7})^{\times}$, which is isomorphic to the additive group $\mathbb{Z}_{4} \times \mathbb{Z}_{6}$. Those three groups are not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$, because $4$ and $6$ are not relatively prime.

Comment: Wait. Is (Z/pZ)^x always isomorphic to Z/(p-1)Z?

Comment: Yes, @actuarialcoder, I'd recommend [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n)